# Button OnClick not firing on first click in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("~/Logon.aspx");
    }
```

this is not working when first click on cancel button?

Comment: Can you also post the button's aspx markup?

Comment: I gave you whole mark up and two kind of buttons. please reply back

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're binding to the event only when `IsPostBack` is `true`. Otherwise we won't know without more code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the markup is correct?

Does it look similar to the following?

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" OnClick="ButtonCancel_Click" />
```

You need the "OnClick" attribute for it to work.

Comment: Also you could add the click event in the codebehind with something like ButtonCancel.Click += delegate { };

Answer (score 0):

do you really need to postback just to go to another page? You can just have a javascript call for that:

```
<input ID="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:window.location='/logon.aspx';" />
```

Comment: it works for me. try creating a new page, put this inside then test.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="save" 
    OnClientClick="return confirmmation()" onclick="Button1_Click"  />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmmation() {
        return confirm('confirm');
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="cancel" CausesValidation="False" 
    onclick="Button2_Click" />
```

On your refrence i tried the same way and it worked.Both button got postback. May I see your button_save_click event code and your page load code.

Answer (score 0):

Do  you have form tag in master page or this page?

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button"  runat="server" onclick="alert('hi'); " onserverclick="Button1_ServerClick"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="alert('hi'); "  />
</asp:Content>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("hello");
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```